# OSError: [WinError 127] when trying to load a DLL fixed by changing the environment [Python]

Tags: python, dll, mingw, ctypes

I've tried to get the tree-sitter parsing library to work in my project in a 64bit python environment using the existing python-binding - unfortunately to no avail. A github issue of said python-binding repo mentioned the library is only compatible with 32bit python versions. Since the library needs to first compile a parser into a DLL before parsing anything, I installed MinGW as a 32bit C(++) compiler and managed to compile the parser. However, when trying to load the DLL I got the following Error:

```
File "D:\Projekte\Idea\Crawler\venv37\lib\site-packages\tree_sitter\__init__.py",
 line 81, in __init__
     self.lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(library_path)  
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 442, in LoadLibrary      
     return self._dlltype(name)     
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) 
OSError: [WinError 127] Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden
```

After a little bit of searching on SO I managed to fix the error by adding `os.environ['PATH'] = "C:/MinGW/bin" + ';' + os.environ['PATH']` to my code before trying to load the DLL. I assume this is due to the fact I used MinGW to compile the DLL in the first place.
**(** for completion's sake: I did change some lines of code in *Python37/lib/distutils/cygwinccompiler.py* to force python to actually use the appropriate compiler, namely changing the linker_so executable in the class `Mingw32CCompiler` to "g++ -shared" and adding

```
elif msc_ver == '1926':
    # Visual Studio 2015 / Visual C++ 14.0
    # "msvcr140.dll no longer exists" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/03/visual-studio-14-ctp.aspx
    return ['vcruntime140']
```

to `get_msvcr()` **)**

Still I'm not quite sure **why** this fixes the error and trying to use the debugger to go through the stacktrace only got me lost in the countless stubs in the `ctypes/__init__.py`. I figured this post could help others that encountered a similar error and myself better understand what the hell is going on.